# gradle generate jar has resource file but running jar causes Invalid resource

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

I have a rest server written in java and using gradle as it build system.

In one my class I am using the file **src/main/resources/myresource.config** as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String resourcePath = Myapplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myresource.config").toURI().getPath();
LOGGER.info(String.format("Loading data from config %s", resourcePath));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourcePath));
}
```

The program works fine when running the class directly from command line or ide.

I am build a jar for my application as below

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.Myapplication',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

The jar gets build successfully inside build/libs
when I try running the jar **java -jar myapplication.jar**
I fails to find the **myresource.config** resource.

I unzipped the build jar and found that the **myresource.config** file is present but the jar fails to run.

Things I have tried so far

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("myresource.config");
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myresource.config")
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing incorrect?

Stacktrace

```
INFO: Loading data from config null
Invalid resource: myresource.config
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.example.Myapplication.<main>(Myapplication.java:26)
```

Comment: In what package is `Myclass` located?

Comment: @dpr com.example package, I tried the same inside the com.example.Myapplication as well it fails there too.

Comment: Could you add the error you get when running the jar file? The exception including the stacktrace.

Comment: @dpr added stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, when running the application from the IDE `myresource.config` is read directly from the file system. That is you get a regular file URL:

```
URL configUrl = Myapplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myresource.config");
// returns "file:/C:/path/to/project/bin/main/myresource.config"
```

But when you execute the application from the jar file, the config file is read from the jar and you get a jar based URL:

```
URL configUrl = Myapplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myresource.config");
// returns "jar:file:/C:/path/to/project/build/libs/myapplication.jar!/myresource.config"
```

This second jar-based URL cannot be converted to a filesystem path and that is why you get `null`.

To get the config in both scenarios, you should do something like this

```
try (final InputStream configInputStream = Myapplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myresource.config");
     final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configInputStream));) {
   // do something with br
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use getResourceAsStream instead.
`Myapplication.class.getResourceAsStream("myresource.config")`

Comment: `Myapplication.class.getResourceAsStream` will load resources relative to `Myapplication.class`. Either use `"/myresource.config"` or `Myapplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myresource.config")`